# Error at runtime using proguard with Firebase: no static method with name='getInstance' in class Ljava.lang.Object;

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, proguard

When I set the Minify options in the Android Player settings to Proguard, I get the following exception at runtime when my app starts up:

```
08/27 15:51:59.099 20405 20481 Error Unity: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method with name='getInstance' signature='(Lcom.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity;)Ljava/lang/Object;' in class Ljava.lang.Object;
08/27 15:51:59.099 20405 20481 Error Unity: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method with name='getInstance' signature='(Lcom.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity;)Ljava/lang/Object;' in class Ljava.lang.Object;
08/27 15:51:59.099 20405 20481 Error Unity:     at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.getMethodID(Unknown Source:167)
08/27 15:51:59.099 20405 20481 Error Unity:     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
08/27 15:51:59.099 20405 20481 Error Unity:     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source:0)
08/27 15:51:59.099 20405 20481 Error Unity:     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source:78)
08/27 15:51:59.099 20405 20481 Error Unity:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08/27 15:51:59.099 20405 20481 Error Unity:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
08/27 15:51:59.099 20405 20481 Error Unity:     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source:20)
08/27 15:51:59.099 20405 20481 Error Unity:   at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
08/27 15:51:59.099 20405 20481 Error Unity:   at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CallStaticObjectMethod (System.IntPtr clazz, System.IntPtr methodID, UnityEngine.jv
```

I'm using Firebase Unity SDK v6.2.2, Unity v2019.1.14f1.

I've tried adding a User Proguard File with a few different variations (based on the Firebase quickstart projects on Github), my last one being this:

```
# Firebase Analytics, AdMob, Dynamic Links, Remote Config, Messaging
# eg. https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/analytics/app/proguard-rules.pro
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes InnerClasses

# Firebase Auth (https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/proguard-rules.pro)
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes InnerClasses

# Firebase Crashlytics (https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/crash/app/proguard-rules.pro)
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
-dontnote org.xmlpull.v1.**
-keep class org.xmlpull.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class org.xmlpull.** { *; }

# Firebase Functions (https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/functions/app/proguard-rules.pro)
# https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1227
-dontwarn com.firebase.ui.auth.data.remote.**

# Random attempts to get this working!
-keep public class com.google.firebase.** {
   public *;
}
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.google.firebase.** { *; }

-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.shaded.fasterxml.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.ietf.jgss.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**

-keep class java.lang.Object { *; }
-keepnames class java.lang.Object { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I added -dontobfuscate to my proguard config file, and the error message in LogCat then gave much more accurate and useful information about which classes were missing (which I then fixed with appropriate -keep class directives.